# How do I dynamically pipe the commands using the string buffer?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
   int i;
   char commandBuffer[3][10]={"ls -l","ll","top"};
   for(i=0 ; i<1 ; i++)
   {
      system("> gksudo cd /home/phoenix | command[i]");
      system("\n");
      printf("%d\n",i);
   }
   printf("The end\n");
}
```

I have a program in which i want to dynamically run the commands using `system()` but the problem arising here is that the string contained in `command[i]` is not being considered as a the input for piping... but this works fine if I manually enter each of the commands such as  `system("> gksudo cd /home/phoenix | ls -l");`

Comment: Please preview your question before clicking submit. This could be cleaned up a bit. That might make people happier to answer it.

Comment: Try adding a better title too ;)

Comment: Yeah, my first thought was to answer, "No." :)

Comment: Use sprintf() with %s to create the string.

Comment: you have assigned the `str` something and entirely ignored it ?

Comment: Please also note that there is no array called `command`, but `commandBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

`system("> gksudo cd /home/phoenix | command[i]");`

Here the "command[i]" is considered as a string literal. So the value of `command[i]` is *not* substituted. you need something like:

```
char cmd_buff[MAX_BUF];

strcpy (cmd_buff, "> gksudo cd /home/phoenix |");
strcat (cmd_buff, command[i]);
```

Note here that the `command[i]` is not inside double quotes. Please read about string constants and identifiers in C to understand this.

Comment: thanks a lot and i have modified the code as suggested by you...the str was just to test a feature and not required as such...

Comment: yes but you have an elementary mistake, you have attempted to use the variable identifier `command` inside a string like "run command"  , so the contents of the variable identified by `command` will not be replaced in the first case and will be as it is but in the next case it will be replaced. please make sure that you understand this elementary thing.